# What causes the focus confirmation lights to blur?

Tags: repair, equipment-damage, canon-600d

[image]

I recently saw that the red lights on some of the focus points are blurred.

The lights in this picture are lights shown during the selection of focus points.  As you can see the lights in the lower parts are blurred.  This blurring was not there earlier.

This is a Canon EOS 600D with no lens attached.

Comment: Comment only: With no lens attached, I'd not be surprised if anything that could happen did happen wrt focus points, as focus is "impossible" [tm]. Also - 'I'd have thought' focus lights are very unlikely to be able to "blur" as they are (presumably) on or off or at best modulated in a point location. Occam suggests that To achieve what you are seeing means something has happened to the viewing system. Occam is not always right :-).

Answer (score 3):

Has the *diopter adjustment dial* on the back of the viewfinder been moved? If everything was clear to your eyes before moving it will make everything in the viewfinder blurry to your eyes.

[image]

To adjust it simply look through the viewfinder and turn it until everything in the viewfinder display (focus points, exposure information, etc.) is sharp. You may have to use a half press of the shutter to light everything up while you adjust it.