# Canon focus points are blurry..Please help!

Tags: canon

[image]

I'm using an Canon 1200d. Lighting up the focus points clearly shows that the focus points are shifted slightly to the down vertically.

I've not had any problems with the focusing system.

Comment: Is it just the focus points or full display when you look in viewfinder?

Answer (score 2):

Use the diopter adjustment knob to the right of the viewfinder to focus the viewfinder information to match your vision. It's the little dial with the "-" and "+" symbols next to it.

To adjust it simply look through the viewfinder and turn it until everything in the viewfinder display (focus points, exposure information, etc.) is sharp. You may have to use a half press of the shutter to light everything up while you adjust it.

[image]

The diopter adjustment wheel is pretty much in the same position across most major camera brands. It is provided to help users who wear glasses (or need to) to adjust the viewfinder to match their prescription so that not only the image from the lens is as clear in the viewfinder as it will be to the sensor, but so the information provided by the camera in the viewfinder is also clear.

For more information please see:
[What causes the focus confirmation lights to blur?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62026/what-causes-the-focus-confirmation-lights-to-blur/62030#62030)
[How do I chose the right "correction eyepiece" when I need to go past the furthest left on a Nikon viewfinder?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65551/how-do-i-chose-the-right-correction-eyepiece-when-i-need-to-go-past-the-furthe/65555#65555) (It's the same for Canon)